# How to install WineASIO on Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: sound, wine, 18.10, jack, additional-drivers

Previous answers to this question incorporated the KXStudio ppa to install the wine-asio driver. However, according to the [KXStudio website](https://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/):

> NOTE: The KXStudio project is currently on a break, regular development is expected to return later in 2019. Thanks for understanding.

I was wondering if there were any other ppa's or Ubuntu repositories that would allow me to install KXStudio (I know that I could also build from source, but I am not sure how to do that).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can still use the PPA they are linking here on kx.studio/Repositories